# Remove UIPickerView Borders

Tags: ios, swift, uipickerview

The default "UIPickerView" has a thin gray line at the top and bottom that I want to remove, but I can't find out how to do that.

Is there a property somewhere that I can set to clear?

Comment: I know it might be a bit dummy, but have you tried putting it inside a UIView with a bit smaller height (Don't forget "clip to bounds") ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to subclass `UIPickerView`, as such:

```
class MyPickerView: UIPickerView {

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()

        self.layer.borderWidth = 0 // Main view rounded border

        // Component borders
        self.subviews.forEach {
            $0.layer.borderWidth = 0
            $0.isHidden = $0.frame.height <= 1.0
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Awesome! That's exactly it! Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

in picker view datasource method

```
 func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {

    pickerView.subviews.forEach({
        $0.isHidden = $0.frame.height < 1.0
    })
    return 1

}
```

the lines will be gone

Answer (score -1):

I think you need to remove the two lines of the selected row, if so then you can use the titleForRow or viewForRow delegate method of pickerView and use the following code in the delegate method.

```
- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
  [[pickerView.subviews objectAtIndex:1] setHidden:TRUE];
  [[pickerView.subviews objectAtIndex:2] setHidden:TRUE];
}
```

OR

```
- (UIView *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView 
            viewForRow:(NSInteger)row 
          forComponent:(NSInteger)component 
           reusingView:(UIView *)view
{
  [[pickerView.subviews objectAtIndex:1] setHidden:TRUE];
  [[pickerView.subviews objectAtIndex:2] setHidden:TRUE];
}
```